# Spelling mistake in Stack Exchange, Inc. API Terms of Use page

Tags: bug, status-completed, legal, spelling

In the [Stack Exchange, Inc. API Terms of Use](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/api-terms-of-use) page, the first paragraph has a word with a spelling mistake.

The word program**m**atically is displayed as programatically (with single m).

> ... a set of programming interfaces which allow you to **programatically** query and connect to the Stack Exchange Network. ...

Comment: Hopefully Shog won't come after you with a giant M now.

Comment: I'm almost sad the title didn't say spelling misteak.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek or "bad gramar"

Comment: related https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12245/frequent-use-of-word-not-found-in-dictionary-programatically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (rev `2018.5.29.30545`).

Thanks to the comments, the commit message for this fix was a no-brainer:

[image: commit message]

Comment: Steak! I'm hungry.

Comment: Wait... what happened to revisions 30534 and 30535? It's only 30533 now...

Comment: We do not talk about 20534 and 30535. (Also, my guess would be they don't deploy every build?)

Comment: @Journeyman oh, bad builds. They should be indeed left alone, never to be mentioned. ;-) (that said, who says 30536 won't be a bad build too?)

Comment: There are some other [gramar misteak in API documentation](https://stackapps.com/q/6899/37357)

Comment: @Arulkumar yeah, I've fixed those too (in the same commit), just needs a build

Comment: @m0sa Oh, great.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the last number in the build revision is propagated from the first build in our build chain (our Dev environment). So we get an incremented number every time a dev build runs / triggers (by one or more commits).

Comment: @m0sa makes sense! So it means you can't really predict the final number that will actually go live... no?

Comment: exactly, but I can give you a number, and if you see a it, or a greater one, it means the fix is deployed

Comment: Well, it's done. Time to [tag:status-completed] the question, no? :)

Comment: whilst you're there would you mind [looking at these ones too](https://stackapps.com/questions/6893/typos-on-api-stackexchange-com-docs-js-lib)? :)